# VS Code ipython/jupyter interactive environment not showing full traceback?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions

Not sure if this is a VS code or Jupyter problem but I have been using Jupyter in VS Code (specifically using the "# %%" implementation outlined [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks)).

I noticed recently that my error tracebacks are not showing the full traceback, but rather only the first layer.

For example, I made a simple dummy error (hiding my path on purpose here):

ran in interactive mode:

```
NameError
Traceback (most recent call last)
[PATH] in <module>
----> 97 py_getAnnotation(["a", "b"])

[PATH] in py_getAnnotation(experiments)

NameError: name 'hold_s' is not defined
```

But running script normally:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File [PATH], line 97, in <module>
    py_getAnnotation(["a", "b"])
  File [PATH], line 77, in py_getAnnotation
    hold_s.name = col
NameError: name 'hold_s' is not defined
```

I recently had to switch from Mac to Windows. So I am not sure if this is a VS Code thing, an iPython setting/version thing, or maybe even an OS-specific thing.

I've never had this happen before. Any ideas would be appreciated.

NOTE:
I tried uninstalling ipython dependencies and reinstalling.

I have tried running `%xmode` as suggested in an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087903/why-isnt-ipython-giving-me-a-full-traceback-for-a-module-ive-written)

Edit: I have also copied and pasted my code into a jupyter notebook at that error traceback is fine. So seems to be VS Code Specific.

Edit: Downgrading VS Code to an earlier version worked! But if anyone has an idea why it happened in the first place that would be appreciated.

Comment: I would love to hear if you found a solution in the meantime! I'm still struggling with this

Comment: @Sebastiaan Only solution that worked for me was downgrading. I have updated since and has been fine. So maybe trial and error with versions?